# Is a subset an element of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given these two sets:

A = {c}

B = {c}

Is B $\in$ A?

Or is above wrong and c $\in$ A and B $\subseteq $ A?

Comment: "Or is rather..." Yes. In fact $B=A$.

Comment: Why the downvotes? What did I say wrong. In fact this is a trivial question, but yet it is something I saw as a legit question in an actual exam, baffled by its simplicity, I wanted to make sure that I am not the only one. So don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, B is not an element of A, but a trivial subset.  $$B\in A \iff\{c\}\in A \iff \{c\} \in \{c\}.$$

This is not true.
However it is true that $\{c\}=\{c\}$ and $\{c\} \in \{\{c\}\}$.

Comment: That's how I see it too. Thanks for verifiying.